# Googlesheet adding unwanted rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two sheets (**Sheet1** and **Mirror**) in a single google spreadsheet. I have some columns in the **Mirror** sheet which are being mirrored from **Sheet1** using an array formula (`={"Firstname";ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("Sheet1!B2:B"))}`).

I have rows being copied automatically from a google form into **Sheet1**. For some reason, periodically, about 500 empty rows are entered into the **Mirror** sheet and I have to manually delete them.

I have these googlesheet functions below that trigger on change. I have only deployed the function **ReadRows** and it works like a charm. Rather than deploying the second function (**DeleteBlankRows**) which might slow down my spreadsheet, I do like to know how I can figure out what is causing the extra periodic 500 blank rows to appear and stop it or I'd like any professional advice you can give.

Please see the sample scripts below. Thanks in advance.

```
function readRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if ((row[1] == 0 || row[1] == '') && (row[2] == 0 || row[2] == '')){
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
      
    }
  }
};

function DeleteBlankRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Mirror');
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if ((row[1] == 0 || row[1] == '')){
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
      
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

The issue is that you need to delete the rows backwards for `Sheet1` and then you don't need to use `DeleteBlankRows` for `Mirror` anymore. Replace your code with this one:

```
function readRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  for (var i = values.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
    var row = values[i];
    if ((row[1] == 0 || row[1] == '') && (row[2] == 0 || row[2] == '')){
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1); 
    }
  }
};
```

---

---

To get rid of empty rows, you can simply [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) them out before you copy them to the target sheet.

**Change:**

```
var values = rows.getValues();
```

**to:**

```
var values = rows.getValues().filter(r=>r[0]!='');
```

Assuming for every empty row, the cell in column A is also empty.

You can now remove the `DeleteBlankRows` unless you want to delete also the rows.

Comment: Hi Marios

Thanks for your feedback. The empty rows are not being copied from another sheet. They are being generated on Mirror sheet.

Comment: @EdawgO. How do you copy the data from the form sheet to Sheet1?

Comment: Using this function:

`function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').appendRow(e.values);
}`

Comment: @EdawgO. I don't have a clear picture of the sheets? if `mirror` sheets has blank rows, so does `Sheet1` right?

Comment: Thank you for being so patient in trying to understand and assist.

I applied a function `ReadRows` which I shared in question that deletes `blank rows` in `sheet1` but the row_ids in column A  of `Mirror` sheet seems to be generating roughly 500 extra rows at various intervals.

Applying the `DeleteBlankRows` function to the `Mirror` sheet will definitely slow things down considering it will have to iterate through 500 rows at various intervals. Is there are better/faster way of doing this where all rows in `Mirror` sheet without data in column 2 or 3 be deleted at once?

Comment: @EdawgO. can you check my updated answer?

Comment: The updated script helps delete the empty rows but still takes a hit as it takes some time to iterate over so many blank rows which is something I'd like to mitigate against. Is there another way to do this? Say store the number of blank rows and instantly delete all? Please forgive me if my request is odd as I am a novice in google sheet scripting.

Comment: @EdawgO. why don't you change the formula that you have in the mirror sheet so you can fetch only non empty rows? That would be the most efficient approach.